# Change check value checkbox form ( Awesomium VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, checked, awesomium

I tried both, but it won't work. Can anyone help me?

```
WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('#signupForm_confirm_terms').prop('checked'", "true")

WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('#signupForm_confirm_terms').attr('checked'", "true")
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('#signupForm_confirm_terms').checked = true;")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Just had to remove de #. My mistake. Thank you very much!